# Python: Replace values while reading CSV file with pandas

Tags: python, pandas

i've a txt file that contains something like this:

```
Struct{a,b,c}
Struct {d,f,z}
```

I'd like to read this file and have this output:

```
  0   1   2
0 a   b   c
1 d   f   z
```

I tried to run this code

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
def conv(val, default_val=''):
    try:
         return (val)
    except ValueError:
         return default_val
x = pd.read_csv('/Users/me/Desktop/connector/connector.txt', sep=",", header=None, converters={'Struct': conv, '{': conv, '}': conv })
print(x)
```

but this is the output:

```
          0  1   2
0  Struct{x  y  z}
1  Struct{a  b  c}
```

can somebody tell me why it doesn't work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't working because parameter `converters` expects a dict of functions for converting values in certain columns. Keys can either be integers or column labels. None of `['Struct','{','}']` is a column label.

In order to read this text file, you would need to preprocess it getting rid of `'Struct', '{', '}'`. I.e. you will need to convert it to a proper CSV file.